# got an error 1004: we can do that to a merged cell.. why?

Tags: excel, vba

got an **Error 1004:** **we can do that to a merged cell**..

Why ?

How can I fix it ?

I want to copy cell in twb to extwb...

This code be like = run -> got an error -> reset macro -> run again -> it work

```
Sub Ke1()

Dim twb As Workbook
Dim extwb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1


Set twb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\faisal.abraham\Documents\Faisal\Travel\CCCPU030732017.xlsx")
Set extwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\faisal.abraham\Documents\Faisal\Travel\CCCPU030732018.xlsx")
'Set twb = Application.Workbooks("CCCPU030732017.xlsx")
'Set extwb = Application.Workbooks("CCCPU030732018.xlsx")

Set rng = twb.Worksheets("PAID").Range("A1:E500")
For i = 5 To rng.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    rng.Cells(i, 1).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 1)
    rng.Cells(i, 2).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 2)
    rng.Cells(i, 3).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 3)
    rng.Cells(i, 4).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 4)
    rng.Cells(i, 5).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 5)
      
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
    
Next i

twb.Close savechanges:=False
extwb.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error ?

Comment: from rng.Cells(i, 1).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have merged cells in `extwb.Worksheets("PAID")` that you're trying to paste in.

That's not going to work - The `.Copy` source needs to be the same size, i.e. if two cells are merged in the destination range, you need to have two merged cells in the source range.

You can resolve this by doing:

```
extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Range("A" & lastRow & ":E" & lastrow).Unmerge
rng.Cells(i, 1).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 1)
rng.Cells(i, 2).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 2)
rng.Cells(i, 3).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 3)
rng.Cells(i, 4).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 4)
rng.Cells(i, 5).Copy extwb.Worksheets("PAID").Cells(lastRow, 5)
```

Comment: Then troubleshoot that line where you set the last row.